# Clearing the console at exactly 30 lines of output and/or UI

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

So I've been working on a project where I want to count up continuously until there are 30 lines of output or user input of a mix of both in the console. Then, I want to clear the console and reset the program. I've tried multiple ways, but none of them work.

I tried the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import curses
import os
import time


item = 0

def main(stdscr):
    """checking for keypress"""
    stdscr.nodelay(True)  # do not wait for input
    return stdscr.getch()

while True:
    if (curses.wrapper(main)) == (-1):  # '0' if no key-presses
      print()
      item += 2
      
    else:
      print('Keypress Detected')
      item += 2

    i = curses.wrapper(main)            # type 'int'
    print(item)                         
# prints the supposed number of lines
# if the user doesn't type more than 1 line
    time.sleep(0.25)
# Time interval
    if item == 30:
      os.system('clear')
      item = 0

# clears console at supposed 30 lines

    else:
      pass # does nothing and repeats program
```

The Output is

```
2

4

6

8

10

12
```

and so on until it reaches 30. then, it resets.

but if the user interupts with more than 1 line:

```
2





4






6



8
```

until it reaches 30, which means the console doesn't refresh in time before the console has more than 30 lines.

Comment: Welcome here to SO. This question is a very specific use-case, may not be very helpful to discuss in full for you as well as by rest later. I suggest you minify your problem to a sub-problem and share that minified source with exact problem to get an answer faster. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask